# Updating numpy 2-dimensional array according to conditions across different 2-D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

In the code that I am writing, I have three 2D numpy arrays with the same dimensions (m x n), with each 2D array containing info about a specific trait, but each corresponding cell (with a specific row/col value) across all three 2D arrays corresponding to a specific person. The three 2D arrays are trait1, trait2, and trait3. As an example, person (0, 0) will have traits 1, 2, but not three, if only trait1 and trait2 have a value of 1 at location (0,0), but trait3 does not.

**What would be an efficient method of updating a 2D array at a specific location based on the values of other corresponding 2D arrays of the same dimension at the same location?** That is, how can I efficiently update a 2D array at a specific location such that the other 2D arrays at this same location fulfill specific conditions?

I am currently trying to update the values of the 2D array trait1 and trait2 according to the current values of trait1 and trait2 (such that the corresponding trait1 value == 1, and the corresponding trait2 value == 0); I am also trying to update the values of trait3 according to the current values of trait1, and trait2 (under the same conditions as the previous). However, I am having trouble doing this without using nested for loops, which greatly slows down my program.

Below is my current approach, which works, but is much too slow for my purposes:

```py
for i in range (0, m):
        for j in range (0, n):
            if trait1[i][j] == 1:
                if trait2[i][j] == 0:
                    trait1[i][j] = 0
                    trait2[i][j] = 1
                    new_color(i, j, 1) #updates the color of the specific person on a grid
                    trait3[i][j] = 0 

            elif trait1[i][j] == 0:
                if trait2[i][j] <= 0:
                    trait1[i][j] = 1
                    trait2[i][j] = 0
                    new_color(i, j, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy array are really slow if you use loop indeed. If you can use matrices operations / numpy function for everything, it will go much faster.
In your case, you could first extract the indices you're interested about, and then update your matrices like this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
# Generate some sample data
trait1, trait2, trait3 = ( np.random.randint(0,2, [4,4]) for _ in range(3) )
```

```
In [4]: trait1
Out[4]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])
In [5]: trait2
Out[5]:
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
In [6]: trait3
Out[6]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

And then:

```
cond1_idx = np.where((trait1 == 1) & (trait2==0))
cond2_idx = np.where((trait1 == 0) & (trait2<=0))

trait1[cond1_idx] = 0
trait2[cond1_idx] = 1
trait3[cond1_idx] = 0
[ new_color(i, j, 1) for i,j in zip(*cond1_idx) ]

trait1[cond2_idx] = 1
trait2[cond2_idx] = 0
[ new_color(i, j, 0) for i,j in zip(*cond2_idx) ]
```

Result:

```
In [2]: trait1
Out[2]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [3]: trait2
Out[3]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [4]: trait3
Out[4]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I cannot really test the `new_color` though since I don't have the function